# Doesn't work if the number of digits bigger than 10

Tags: c

I want to make program that input number and print two numbers, one is all the odd digits and the second is all the even digits.

it works fine if the number of the input's digits is less the 10 but when it gets number with 10 and more digits something get wrong. Do you know why?

```
unsigned long int n;
unsigned long int even=0,odd=0;
int countOdd=1,countEven=1;

printf("enter every number: \n");
scanf("%lu",&n);

 while(n!=0){
   if(n%2==0){
        even+=10*countEven*(n%10);
        countEven*=10;
              }
   else
       {
        odd+=10*countOdd*(n%10);
        countOdd*=10;

       }
   n=n/10;
   }
printf("the odd number is %d \n",odd/10);
printf("the even number is %d \n\n\n",even/10);
```

Comment: What does not work? What gets wrong? What do you input? What do you expect? What do you have? What have you tried?

Comment: Instead of `countEven*=10`, you can remove that variable and use `even *= 10;` before you're adding the digit. Same thing with odd numbers.

Comment: Are you using an integer data type capable of storing numbers of 10 digit or more?

Comment: 32bit `long unsigned` values go from 0 to 4294967295 only (as you can see, it is just in the range of 10 digit values)

Answer (score 4):

`unsigned long` is probably 32-bit on your machine, the biggest value that it can hold is 2<sup>32</sup> - 1 (`4294967295`), you are probably inputting a number that is bigger.

Try `unsigned long long` instead, which is at least 64-bit.

Comment: or use `#include <stdint.h>` and use `uint64_t` (`unsigned long long` is a gcc-only feature)

Comment: @LuisColorado Not really, `long long` is a standard C type since C99. So is `stdint.h`.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to remember.  Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared `n` as `unsigned long int` which can hold maximum value of `4,294,967,295` in a 32 bit system. So when you enter the value which exceeds this the maximum value `4294967296` it outputs

```
 odd 99795
 even 42462
```